# get all children of specific parent in node js

Tags: javascript

I want to get all children of specific parent. I am new to node.js and not able to write recursive function to do this task

```
var roots = [1,2,6];

var documents = [
{
    "parent_id":1   
    ,childerens:[4,5]
}

,{
    "parent_id":4   
    ,childerens:[9]
}

,{
    "parent_id":9   
    ,childerens:[]
}

,{
    "parent_id":5   
    ,childerens:[3]
}

,{
    "parent_id":3   
    ,childerens:[]
}

]

roots.forEach(function (rootParentId) {
    var allchilderens=getAllchild(rootParentId);

})
```

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
var allchilderens = getAllchild(1);
allchilderens == [4,5,9,3]
```

Comment: Why aren't you able to write a recursive function for this?

Comment: i can't visualize recursion

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with Node.JS.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Is this a restriction or just something you (personally) can't figure out?

Comment: @AakashKag Visualize a [tree](https://www.google.com/search?q=recursive+tree&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTnoiT18bVAhVo7oMKHdw7CjIQ_AUICigB&biw=1920&bih=974).

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek thanks for link , btw i am able to visualize tree , i am not able to code recursive function. guys do you think we can write non recursive function to do this task ?

Comment: It is possible to use a loop to implement an equivalent to traditional function recursion, but generally (in my subjective opinion) the recursive version is *easier* to visualise, not harder. In any case for this particular problem, conceptually you would still be recursing through your tree data structure.

Comment: @AakashKag While recursion can be confusing at first, it's an important aspect to know as a developer. Recursion is just running a function within itself until you hit some base case where the recursion stops. One basic example is the factorial function (ex: `!5 = 5*4*3*2*1`). Say you had a function to compute factorial `fact(...)`, in this case `fact(5) = 5 * fact(4)`. This is where recursion comes in. We can say to compute `fact(n)` we return `n * fact(n-1)`. In this case the base case where we stop this is once we hit `fact(0)` we would just return `1`.

Comment: @AakashKag Here is a [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/yyrdqrkg/1/). With a comment explaining each step. Hopefully that clarifies recursion a bit.

Comment: function findAllChildren(element) {
 console.log("element==>",element);
 var doc = documents.find(o => o.parent_id === element);
 if(doc["childerens"].length==0){
  return [];
 }
 else{
  doc["childerens"].forEach(function (element) {
   findAllChildren(element);
  })
 } 
} 

console.log(findAllChildren(1));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function findAllChildren(element,is_root,childerens) {
    if(is_root==false&&element!=undefined){
        childerens.push(element);   
    }
    var doc = documents.find(o => o.parent_id === element);
    if(doc["childerens"].length==0){
        return [];
    }
    else{
        doc["childerens"].forEach(function (element) {
            findAllChildren(element,false,childerens);
        })
    }   
} 

var childerens=[];
console.log(findAllChildren(1,true,childerens));
console.log("childerens==>",childerens);
```

Answer (score 0):

You really want to build a tree structure here as step one.

Each object should, instead of containing a list of children ids, it should contain the actual children.  That way, when you want to get all children, you can traverse that tree.

Comment: i am not able to code recursive function. guys do you think we can write non recursive function to do this task ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably should consider revising your data structure here. Why not use an object, where the user id is the key (since it should be unique). Then you would just need to get those keys directly.

Having everything inside of an array is potentially bad, since you'd have to iterate through the array to find each child, which would have (at worst), a run time equal to the length of the array.